# Why $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$ of a vector that is sitting on the z-axis corresponds to $\hat{z}$ and $\hat{x}$ respectively?

Tags: vector-spaces

[image]
In the picture, the components of the vector is $\overrightarrow{v}=(vcos\theta)\hat{r}+(vsin\theta)\hat{\theta}$

Someone tipped me that since the vector is sitting on the z-axis
$\hat{r}$ corresponds to $\hat{z}$ and $\hat{\theta}$ corresponds to $\hat{x}$
and I don't get that.

To clarify, the vector is situated $z$ distance from the $z=0$ and it makes an angle $\theta$ with the perpendicular to the plane

Why is that?
I don't intuitively get it.

Answer (score 2):

In spherical coordinates, $r$ is the length of the vector, $\theta$ is the angle between it and the $z$ axis, and $\phi$ is the angle between the vector's projection into the $xy$-plane and the $x$-axis. The unit vectors point in the direction the coordinate is increasing. So $\hat{r}$ points directly outward, $\theta$ will be tangent to a semicircle from $+\hat{z}$ to $-\hat{z}$, and $\hat{\phi}$ will be tangent to a circle around the $z$-axis.

Now, if $\theta = 0$ and $\phi = 0$, the vector will be parallel to the $z$ axis. Then $\hat{r}$ will be equal to $\hat{z}$, since the direction of increasing $r$ is in the same direction as the vector. $\hat{\theta}$ will be equal to $\hat{x}$, because at that point the semicircle that $\hat{\theta}$ is tangent to is horizontal, and since $\phi = 0$, it is parallel to the $x$-axis. This correspondence only happens when $\theta = 0$. For any other value of $\theta$, $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$ will be some other linear combination of $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{z}$ (and $\hat{y}$ if $\phi \ne 0$).

Comment: If $\theta=0$, then $\phi$ can be anything and you would still be on the positive $z$-axis, so $\hat{\theta}$ isn't well-defined there.

Comment: @HansLundmark True, but if you allow for $\phi$ to have a defined value even though $(r,0,\phi)$ describes the same point for all $\phi$, you can still talk about a definite $\hat{\theta}$. In a lot of applications, continuity will imply which value of $\phi$ you should be considering.

Comment: Just as a heads up for future readers. The convention for which angle is measured where isn't uniform and varies text by text and author by author. Some have $\theta$ be the angle in the $xy$-plane and $\varphi$ be the angle from $z$ and vice versa. I think the IEEE standard is $\theta$ from the $z$, but not everyone adheres to it.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Also a good point. In particular, I find that mathematicians tend to have $\phi$ be the polar angle (angle with respect to $z$) while physicists prefer $\theta$. My convention here betrays which side I'm on.